# Can't get token passed to my code from a Google Workspace Add-on

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Workspace Add-on and am following the documentation from here

https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#id_tokens

I can't get `authorizationEventObject`. It should be passed by google (gmail, calendar, ...) by the call but it is undefined.

Comment: Please obfuscate (!) but include the deployment resource you're using and the event object you're receiving.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @DazWilkin the problem isn't that it isn't working. Everything works fine but the request coming from the google addon doesn't pass any event object at all. I'm wondering if it's not published yet and therefore not sending it. I'll post the code I have. Anything else in terms of config I should add?

Comment: IIUC you need to define a [deployment resource](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#example_deployment_resource) and this includes specific config/scopes for e.g. Gmail. When your addon is invoked by the User, your code's endpoint will receive an [event object](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#validate_json_requests). Both of these would be useful to help answer your question.